# "python setup.py install" command doesn't install libs in install_requires list

Tags: python, ubuntu, debian, deb, python-packaging

My goal is creating .deb package from a python package and distribute my python scripts at the end. I have 2 questions about this process

1- I am able to create a python package with following steps in [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-package-and-distribute-python-applications). My setup.py is like that

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
# Application name:
name="MyApplication",

# Version number (initial):
version="0.1.0",

# Application author details:
author="name surname",
author_email="name@addr.ess",

# Packages
packages=["app"],

# Include additional files into the package
include_package_data=True,

# Details
url="http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MyApplication_v010/",

#
# license="LICENSE.txt",
description="Useful towel-related stuff.",

# long_description=open("README.txt").read(),

# Dependent packages (distributions)
install_requires=[
    "simplejson",
    "numpy",
    "scikit-learn",
    "scipy",
 ],
)
```

Things are starting to be different in the install_requires part. I know those libs can be installed via pip so in this case after I created the python package and it creates tar.gz of the package. So

**python setup.py install** command doesn't install the libs in the install_requires list but if I call the python package tar.gz with **pip install name_of_the_package.tar.gz** it installs the libs in the list. So why **python setup.py install** command don't install the libs?

2- Then I am creating the .deb package from my python package using [stdeb](http://shallowsky.com/blog/programming/python-debian-packages-w-stdeb.html). When I try to install .deb package to my system, I am expecting to get libs installed in the install_requires list but they don't get installed?

I feel like I am skipping a part but I don't know what I am skipping?

Comment: The `install_requires` keyword argument to the `setup()` function is a [`setuptools` feature](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies), it's not supported as such in plain `distutils`. If you instead import the setup function from setuptools using `from setuptools import setup` it might just work. That guide on digitalocean seems incorrect and outdated. I would recommend following the official packaging guide at https://packaging.python.org/current/ instead.

Comment: @LukasGraf thank you for the response, I am going to try that and get back to here soon.

Comment: @LukasGraf I tried that `python setup.py install` installs required packages but somehow `python setup.py install` command stuck at  `Building wheels for collected packages: <name of project >
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for <name of project > ... |` Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @LukasGraf thank you, that solved both of the problems I have, if you add the answer I can mark as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `install_requires` keyword argument to the `setup()` function is a [setuptools feature](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies), it's not supported as such in plain `distutils`.

If you instead import the `setup` function from `setuptools` using

```
from setuptools import setup
```

it might just work.

That guide on DigitalOcean seems incorrect and outdated. I would recommend following the official packaging guide at https://packaging.python.org/ instead.